# How to download Firestore collection documents to my Local pc

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

How can I download firestore collections to my local pc to make a process then upload it again to firestore.

I downloaded the collection from gcloud console but the collection did not open and the format is different than what is in firestore.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you downloaded a backup of the data, which is not really in a format meant for editing.

I'd probably use the API to [download the documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), store them in a format that works for you, and then [reupload them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) through the API again.